# The omission of articles before the word "year" in context

Tags: articles, zero-article

Here is the context:

> Christmas is an especially difficult time of (**a**) year, but my kids and my husband have been really supportive and I'm much better now.

It is from this [article](http://Christmas%20is%20an%20especially%20difficult%20time%20of%20year,%20but%20my%20kids%20and%20my%20husband%20have%20been%20really%20supportive%20and%20I'm%20much%20better%20now.%22). I am aware that the person tell us not about a specific year there, so logically the indefinite article should have been used. I am confused becausd the word [*year*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/year) is countable.

Comment: [this time of (the) year](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+time+of+year%2Cthis+time+of+the+year&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20time%20of%20year%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20time%20of%20the%20year%3B%2Cc0) on Ngram

Comment: **Time of year** , like **time of day**, is idiomatic - an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

> Christmas is an especially difficult **time of year**, but my kids and my husband have been really supportive and I'm much better now.

The main noun here is *time*, not *year*. *year* only describes the specific "time" being spoken of, and as such is a modifier. So an article for *time* but none for *year*.

But you could use one if you are specifically referring to the year. For example,

> It was that **time of the year** to go shopping.